# Get Google drive shareable link without allowing user to download file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How to get a Google Doc link(shareable link) using python, without allowing user to download it?

Answer (score 1):

- You can obtain e.g. the `webViewLink` of the file which allows the user to open the file - for example using the method [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) or [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and specifying in fields to retrieve `webViewLink`

> Sample:

`myLink = service.files().list(fields="files(id, name, webViewLink)").execute()`

- The download options depend on your sharing permissions. You can change them  programmatically by specifying the `labels.restricted` field of the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)